# For a Cycle Graph is there only one Spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory

For example a Cycle Graph C200 has only 1 spanning tree right?

Because adding just one edge to a spanning tree will create a cycle?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, $C_n$ will have $n$ spanning trees ($n$ choices for the edge you you delete). But they are all isomorphic (paths of length $n-1$), so it depends on whether you want to consider them as distinct or the same.

Comment: So would a Cyclic graph ie, $C_100$ will have 100 spanning trees

Comment: @Bloer yes it would

Comment: @Bloer: Hint:  to get multidigit subscripts, enclose them in braces, so C_{100} will give $C_{100}$ instead of C_100 giving $C_100$